# Como modifico los titulos de un jTable en tiempo de ejecucion Java?

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
    String x[][]={};
    String columns[]= {"Programa","Estudiante","Modalidad"};
    model = new DefaultTableModel(x,columns);
    table.setModel(model);
```

Y me gustaria modificar los titulos de esta tabla, que son los que estan en columns durante la ejecucion del programa, me podrian ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese cambio durante el runtime se puede lograr empleando un `TableColumn` con el cual es posible modificar la información via `setHeaderValue(String)`, suponiendo que se dispone de un método para dicha tarea:

```
private void updateHeader() {
  javax.swing.table.TableColumn TC;
  for(int i=0; i<table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    TC = table.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
    TC.setHeaderValue("Titulo "+(i+1));
  }
}
```

En la linea 4 basicamente se saca la columna del encabezado de la tabla y finalmente se procede a la modificación de los datos con el método `setHeaderValue` anteriormente mencionado.